# Keras: How to use fit_generator with multiple images input and one output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, generator

Is it possible make that fit_generator?

I'm creating a U-net network and I want to use as input a picture high 500, weight 500, and 5 channels, and on the output   high 500, weight 500, and 1 channel

[image: model configuration]

if it is not possible - i can create 500x500x5 np.arrays by myself and then I'll need a generator for load numpy objects from HDD

my code now (just for rgb picture)

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/data/',
                                                  target_size=(500,500),
                                                  color_mode='rgb',
                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                  class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own generator. It is essential to get a `while True :` structure and `yield` your data. The code looks like this

```
batch_size=16
step_ep=data_size//batch_size

def generator():
  while True:
    for i in range(step_ep):
       process your images
       X=images
       Y=labels
       yield X,Y
```

With `X` of shape `(batch_size,height,width,channel)`
and `Y`of shape `(batch_size,height,width,output_channel)`

You should use `model.fit()` instead of `model.fit_generator` because it will be soon deprecated.

You can also create a generator for your validation data.

Your `model.fit()` looks like :

```
model.fit(generator(),epochs,steps_per_epoch=step_ep, 
          validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=val_steps)
```